# How to convert from string to RAW(Oracle) in php?

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to pass a long strings to Oracle stored procedure RAW variable but getting an error:

> oci_execute(): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Not sure how to convert String to Raw datatype.

Comment: `your_stroed_procedure(utl_raw.CAST_TO_RAW('Long string'));`

Comment: I need to convert it when calling it from php web application

Answer (score 2):

select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('test') from dual
-- 74657374

echo bin2hex('test');
-- 74657374